# onClick function of INPUT element (type=checkbox) is not being called due to javascript applied to stylize the check boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a list of selectable items with checkboxes and I have applied a javascript to stylize the checkboxes. I have written a JS function to select all items of the list. It works fine when there is no styling JS applied on the checkboxes but when I apply the JS, the function in "onClick" is not being invoked.

Below is my code:

1) The code which renders to HTML table

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" onclick="checkall(this)" />
</HeaderTemplate>
```

2)checkAll function

```
function checkall(objRef) {
            var GridView = objRef.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
            var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
                //Get the Cell To find out ColumnIndex
                var row = inputList[i].parentNode.parentNode;
                if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && objRef != inputList[i]) {
                    if (objRef.checked) {
                        //If the header checkbox is checked
                        //check all checkboxes
                        inputList[i].checked = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        inputList[i].checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

3) A JS due to which problem occurs

```
<script src="assets/js/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_futurico',
                radioClass: 'iradio_futurico',
                increaseArea: '20%' // optional
            });
        });
</script>
```

It would be very appreciable if I could get some help on the same. Many thanks in advance folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the plugin you are using you will have to use the following syntax to check all boxes:

```
$('input').iCheck('check');
```

And the following to uncheck all checkboxes:

```
$('input').iCheck('uncheck');
```

See the methods sections in the **[DOCS](http://icheck.fronteed.com/)**.

**NOTE:** if you `check` the default checkbox, it will not check the checkbox element of the iCheck plugin.

**EDIT::**

So in your case you could add a click handler and toggle the checkboxs:

```
$(document).on('click', '#checkAll' , function(){
      if($('input:checkbox:checked')) {
           $('input').iCheck('check');
      } else {
           $('input').iCheck('uncheck'); 
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexander but could you please elaborate? Because it selects all boxes on page load itself while I want them be selected on clicking the top check box only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the radio button in you `ready()` function as:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[type="checkbox"]').iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_futurico',
            radioClass: 'iradio_futurico',
            increaseArea: '20%' // optional
        });
    });
```

Also you can specify id of your radio button here